# admob with nativescript-vue integration

Tags: vuejs2, admob, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to add admob to my app with "nativescript-admob", here is the code i have for now :

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
   <StackLayout class="hello-world">
    <Label text="my home page"/>
  </StackLayout>
 </Page>
</template> 

<script>
const admob = require("nativescript-admob");
export default  {   
  mounted() {
    admob.createBanner({
   // if this 'view' property is not set, the banner is overlayed on the current top most view
   // view: ..,
   testing: true, // set to false to get real banners
   size: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER, // anything in admob.AD_SIZE, like admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER
   androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAA", // add your own
   margins: {
    // if both are set, top wins
    //top: 10
    bottom: 50
  },
  }).then(
    function() {
      console.log("admob createBanner done");
    },
   function(error) {
     console.log("admob createBanner error: " + error);
    }
 )
},

}
</script>
```

i try to launch the admob on "mounted" but i cant make it work, does anyone integrated admob this way with nativescript-vue ? in my case i don't even see the log "admob createBanner done" log so maybe i don't use this plugin well.

Comment: Do a `npm run clean` then try again, please.

Comment: i did it and i still have an error : 'admob createBanner error: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method \'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()\' on a null objectreference

Comment: if you do `tns debug` you'll see the following error: `'Error in admob.createBanner: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'utils.ios.getter(UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication).keyWindow.rootViewController')'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the admob.createBanner() function has to be surrounded by a setTimeout() to launch after, it seems it has to be launch when a page is fully loaded. thx for the help of the slack nativescript-vue channel contributors !

Comment: If it just needs to be loaded when the page is loaded you can add @loaded="yourFunction" to the page tag and it will fire yourFunction when the page element is loaded. You should be able to run your admob.createBanner() code inside that function. If it works, its a little better than relying on setTimeout() as time for loading elements can vary for different devices.